# Print some pages duplex and some not

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2007, duplex

In Word (2007), is it possible to set some pages to print duplex and some not?

For example, I'd like the title and contents to not be duplex, and then most of the rest of the document to be duplex.

The only exceptions would be the 3 or 4 occurrences of full-page images printed one page after another, as even using higher quality papers the images bleed through the paper a little. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When printing a document, typically you can only choose either simplex **OR** duplex, but not a combination of both.

To get around this, adjust the formatting of the document by inserting a blank page (insert page break) so you have a blank page before/after the page you wish to only print one-sided. Then print the entire document in duplex.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that would do the job. I hadn't thought about it that way!

Comment: Solution technically works but turns into a manual nightmare as you have to go around adjusting where the extra pages are anytime anything changes the number of pages in the document.

Comment: @Elliot I didn't claim it would be "easy peasy". I offered a solution for the situation at hand. If you know of a better way, by all meants post it as an answer. This site is all about sharing solutions to make things better.